# Cambio de fuente en los sitios Stack Exchange

Tags: característica-nueva, stackexchange, diseño

### ¿Qué?

Se han especificado las fuentes del sistema en Stack Overflow y en la red de Stack Exchange. En macOS e iOS, verás las cosas establecidas en San Francisco. En Windows, verás Segoe. En Android verás Roboto. En Ubuntu aparecerá, bueno, Ubuntu. También utilizaremos sus equivalentes monoespaciados cuando escribamos en el código o representemos las teclas del teclado.

| OS | Sans | Mono |
| --- | --- | --- |
| macOS | San Francisco | San Francisco Mono |
| iOS | San Francisco | San Francisco Mono |
| Windows | Segoe UI | Consolas, or Cascadia Mono, Segoe UI Mono if you've installed those manually |
| Ubuntu | Ubuntu | Ubuntu Mono |
| Android | Roboto | Roboto Mono |
| Chrome OS | Roboto | Roboto Mono |
| Fallback | `sans-serif` | Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, `monospace` |

Vamos a dejar las fuentes con serifa solas, así que se quedarán como Georgia, Cambria, Times New Roman, Times, y luego `serif` como alternativa. De todos modos, no hacemos mucho con las serifas y no queremos estropear los temas que dependen de ellas.

Esta es la pila exacta de fuentes que hemos especificado y que ha visto la luz el día 10.

```
@ff-sans:
    system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, // San Francisco en macOS e iOS
    "Segoe UI", // Windows
    "Ubuntu", // Ubuntu
    "Roboto", "Noto Sans", "Droid Sans", // Chrome OS y Android con fallbacks
    sans-serif; // El último recurso para renderizar en sans-serif.
@ff-serif: Georgia, Cambria, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
@ff-mono:
    ui-monospace, // San Francisco Mono en macOS e iOS
    "Cascadia Mono", "Segoe UI Mono", // Nuevas fuentes monospace de Windows que se instalan opcionalmente. Lo más probable es que se rendericen en Consolas
    "Ubuntu Mono", // Ubuntu
    "Roboto Mono", // Chrome OS y Android
    Menlo, Mónaco, Consolas, // Algunas opciones sensatas de fuentes del sistema
    monospace; // El último recurso para renderizar en monospace.
```

#### ¿Por qué?

Mark Otto lo explicó muy bien en su blog personal, documentando [la razón de GitHub](https://markdotto.com/2018/02/07/github-system-fonts/) para el cambio. Al igual que GitHub, nuestra pila original de fuentes utilizaba Arial en macOS, iOS y Windows. Arial se creó por primera vez en 1982, y ha servido bien a la web durante *décadas*. Pero la tecnología avanza. Los tipos de letra de los sistemas modernos se ven mejor tanto en las nuevas pantallas de alto DPI como en las antiguas. La San Francisco de Apple y la Segoe de Microsoft se ven muy bien en las pantallas retina, tienen pesos más expresivos y mejoran la legibilidad en todos los contextos. Con más pesos, podemos tener una mejor jerarquía. También podemos ser más expresivos. Por ejemplo, en modo oscuro, podríamos [reducir un poco los pesos de nuestras fuentes para mejorar la legibilidad](https://css-tricks.com/dark-mode-and-variable-fonts/).

#### Pero, ¿qué pasa con la coherencia?

En un principio elegimos Arial porque estaba disponible en el mayor número de dispositivos, lo que nos permitía tener una experiencia consistente estés donde estés. Sin embargo, Arial no está disponible en las distribuciones de Linux ni en los dispositivos Android. Actualmente solo conseguimos la coherencia entre macOS, iOS y Windows, dejando que dos plataformas elijan su fuente de sistema. Preferiríamos que la consistencia se trasladara al propio dispositivo: cuando se vea Stack Overflow en iOS, se sentirá mucho más nativo en San Francisco. Lo mismo ocurre con Android, que ya se muestra en Roboto.

También debemos tener en cuenta que antes de estos cambios, nuestra pila de fuentes monoespaciadas variaba mucho. Ahora tendrás una mejor consistencia entre sans y monospace, ya que haremos todo lo posible para elegir los emparejamientos correctos.

#### ¿Perderá mi sitio de Stack Exchange su fuente personalizada?

No. Este cambio no afectará a los sitios que tienen sus propios tipos de letra. Los sitios como Christianity y English seguirán mostrándose con sus fuentes personalizadas.

#### Posibilidades futuras

Si la coherencia fuera el objetivo absoluto, enviaríamos nuestro propio tipo de letra personalizado. Me encantaría poder expresar realmente nuestra marca a través de un tipo de letra, pero eso significa que los usuarios tendrían que descargar las fuentes personalizadas y esperar a que se muestren. También tendríamos que cubrir los conjuntos de caracteres internacionales. La visualización de fuentes personalizadas es cada vez más realista a nuestra escala, así que es posible que volvamos a plantearnos esa opción en algún momento y que volvamos a una experiencia más coherente. Las fuentes del sistema nos permiten modernizarnos mientras tanto sin demasiados inconvenientes.

Además, como gran parte de nuestro sitio se construye con nuestro [sistema de diseño](https://www.stackoverflow.design/), podemos almacenar estas pilas de fuentes como variables CSS. Podríamos permitir a los usuarios especificar más fácilmente los tipos de letra aptos para la dislexia, o cargar los suyos propios por completo.

#### Algunas capturas de pantalla

**Safari en macOS**
[image: Safari en macOS]

**Firefox en Windows**
[image: Firefox en Windows]

**Firefox en Ubuntu**
[image: Firefox en Ubuntu]

Publicado en Meta.SE: [We are switching to system fonts on May 10, 2021](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/364048/)